# Drawable Arrow in XXHDPI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I'm having an issue with the S4. I have my header which is being populated with text and a resource.

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
if (group != null && channel != null) {

builder.append(group.name.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH));

int length = group.name.length();
builder.append("  ");
Drawable arrow = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_right);
arrow.setBounds(0, 0, 13, 30);
ImageSpan myImage = new ImageSpan(arrow);
builder.append(" ");
builder.setSpan(myImage, length + 1, length + 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

builder.append(channel.name.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH));

header.backgroundColor(group.getUIColor());
```

The arrow appears a lot smaller on this higher resolution device. I added a new resource folder drawable-xxhdpi and quadrupled the image size and put it in that folder but the arrow size or placement doesn't change. Am i missing something?

S4:

[image: On S4]

On other devices:

[image: Other devices]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arrow.setBounds(0, 0, 13, 30);
```

You are limiting the size of the drawable, so even if you expand the image size, the drawable will have 13 x 30 pixels. Try not to limit this or take into account the density of the screen and multiply the bounds by the density.